# Get error when build E_CSC_USER_NOTAUTHORIZED: This statement requires USE permissions for database 'master'

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I've been trying to build my U-SQL script and I've even used the example one below:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Newtonsoft.Json] FROM      "assemblies/Newtonsoft.Json.dll";
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats] FROM "assemblies/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll";

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

DECLARE @INPUT_FILE string = @"/Samples/Data/json/donut.json";

//Extract the sps property from the Json file as a string.
    @json =
EXTRACT sps string
FROM @INPUT_FILE
USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

@json =
    SELECT sps.Replace("\r\n", "") AS sps
    FROM @json;


/*
Parse the sps property to extract the id and name values as a SQL.MAP
*/
@sps_json = 
    SELECT Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(sps, "$..id") AS sp_id_map, 
       Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(sps, "$..type") AS sp_type_map
FROM @json;

/*
Explode the id and type maps to get the values of the Id and type as individual rowsets
*/

@sps_id_property =
SELECT id_name.Split('.')[0] AS id_name,
       id_value
FROM @sps_json
     CROSS APPLY
         EXPLODE(sp_id_map) AS T(id_name, id_value);
@sps_type_property =
SELECT type_name.Split('.')[0] AS type_name,
       type_value
FROM @sps_json
     CROSS APPLY
         EXPLODE(sp_type_map) AS T(type_name, type_value);

/*
JOIN the Id and Value maps to return the properties as a rowset

Output of the following JOIN statement
1001,Regular
1002,Chocolate
1003,Blueberry
1004,Devil's Food
*/
@sps = SELECT [id].id_value AS id, [type].type_value AS type
                              FROM @sps_id_property AS [id]
                              INNER JOIN @sps_type_property AS [type]
ON id.id_name == type.type_name;

  /* 
  Output the file.
  */

  OUTPUT @sps
  TO "/rukmanig/output/sps.csv"
  USING Outputters.Csv(quoting : false);
```

However, when I build this, I get the following error:

E_CSC_USER_NOTAUTHORIZED: This statement requires USE permissions for database 'master'

I have no idea why I have this.  My other colleague when he builds the same project has no problems.  I was able to build before, but for some reason I can't anymore.

Anybody know why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have been able to fix it. But after we introduced file and folder and DB level ACLs, existing users on existing accounts needed to be given explicit permissions on the master database.

Newly added users or newly created accounts should do it automatically.